# Reference .NET 4.0 project from Core project

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a classic .NET 4.0 project with a public class `Foo`:

```csharp
public class Foo
{
}
```

I also have a Core project with xUnit referenced:

```csharp
class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

However this doesn't compile as `Foo` isn't found.

The `csproj` file for the core project looks like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputTypeEx>library</OutputTypeEx>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Junk.CSharp.Classic.Library\Junk.CSharp.Classic.Library.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Can a .NET Core project reference a Framework 4.0 project?

Comment: Why cannot you search before posting. Too many duplicates.

Comment: @LexLi  Thanks for searching for me!